# Converting a date to string in SQL Server stored procedure results

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, type-conversion

**Background**

I am a beginner to SQL. I have written a SQL Server stored procedure that pulls certain data from a table from the previous month and displays the results. The results are then saved and sent to via email as a .csv (this is not part of the stored procedure).

**Objective**

As per the last line of sequel from the *stored procedure SQL*, I am trying to ensure that certain column values from the results are converted to strings, however not altering the table the stored procedure is querying. The current values in the columns I'm trying to convert to string are `2020-12-01 09:20:00.000`

**Issue**

When I run the stored procedure, I get an invalid column name error, and as the column `trade_date` **is** valid, I'm sure its just my lousy attempt.

This is my stored procedure:

```
SELECT *
FROM tom..blot_v
WHERE trade_date BETWEEN DATEADD(DAY, 1, EOMONTH(GETDATE(), -2)) 
                     AND EOMONTH(GETDATE(), -1)
  AND type NOT IN ('cancel', 'ORDER-FILLED', 'ORDER-UNFILLED') 
  AND trade_type = 'QR'
ORDER BY trade_date

SELECT CONVERT(varchar, trade_date, 20)
```

**Help**

Is anyone able to advise where I'm going wrong with my code, specifically the

```
SELECT CONVERT(varchar, trade_date, 20)
```

which was my attempt to try converting the output of the *trade_date* value, before attempting for others.

Comment: Your final query is missing a `FROM`; `trade_date` has no context.

Comment: move your convert up to where you have select *.  Then specify the columns you want, do not select * (you should never select *).

Comment: Please show the actual error.

Comment: Yeah.. don't. Pass the dates through to whatever front end youre using, as dates rather than strings. Get into the habit of keeping data in its original format right the way up to the point where you finally write it to disk or whatever. If you don't then you'll have all these sprocs that format stuff as strings, and then someone will come along with something else front endy and "oh, I'll just use that already existing thing", then "oh, the dates are strings.. I'll just parse them back so I can work with them", then "oh, it's lost its timezone info etc and that's caused a stupid bug.."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Barring whether you should or not, based on the code you have presented, the reason you are getting column errors is that even though you may think that because you ran the query above it, that the field is available, it is not.

If you wanted to convert a field to text, you should do it while the query is running and there is access to the data.
So this means:

```
SELECT CONVERT(varchar, trade_date, 20) as tradedate, * 
FROM tom..blot_v
WHERE trade_date BETWEEN DATEADD(DAY, 1, EOMONTH(GETDATE(), -2)) 
                     AND EOMONTH(GETDATE(), -1)
  AND type NOT IN ('cancel', 'ORDER-FILLED', 'ORDER-UNFILLED') 
  AND trade_type = 'QR'
ORDER BY trade_date
```